# Where to store PDF files from user input in a React/Django project

Tags: reactjs, django, amazon-web-services, filefield

I am creating an job application website with React and Django. I want the users to upload 3 PDF files as part of the form in the application. I want to store these files in the backend(Django) and send the files to another React page. My problem is storing these PDF files. The application model uses FileField. Can these files be stored in Django or is it better to use somehting like AWS?

Comment: Look at Storing PDF files in an Amazon S3 bucket

Answer (score 0):

It is generally an anti-pattern to store user data inside of your application. Data and code should be strictly separated. Otherwise you will run into several issues when reaching topics like backups, cost or deployment.

As @smac2020 mentioned, you should use S3 to store uploaded files. You can use AWS Amplify to upload the files directly into the bucket. Use a S3 bucket policy to restrict public access to put objects and forbid reading from the bucket for normal users.